# javaの環境構築におけるjdk無印とjdk-develの使い分けについて

Tags: java, amazon-linux

### 前置き

elasticsearchをAWS EC2 AmazonLinuxにインストールするにあたって、
java8以降が必要とのことでもともとjava7がインストールされてたところにjava8をyum installしようとしています。

下記の二種類があるようなのですが、どちらをインストールすべきか迷っています。
java-1.8.0-openjdk
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

ちょっとしらべたところdevelのほうは開発環境が必要な場合(javacなど)は無印にプラスして、develのインストールも必要。

### 質問1

開発はしないけどjavaのランタイムが欲しい場合は無印をインストールという使い分けに思えますがあってますか？

まとめると下記のような感じ。
javaで実装されたソフトウェアを動かしたい -> 無印だけで十分
javaで開発したい -> develが必要

### 質問２

ちなみに、develをインストールすれば無印は必要ないということはないでしょうか？

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: よく考えたら、develをyum installして無印が必要な場合は依存関係解消のためにインストールされそうですね（というかされた

Answer (score 3, accepted):

今回の Java に限らず、rpm パッケージを始めとした Linux のパッケージシステムにおいては、
`*-devel` と付くものは大抵その言語に必要なヘッダファイル等が含まれるパッケージとなります。

`yum info <PACKAGE_NAME>` でパッケージのサマリ(説明等)を確認できますが、openjdk に関しては以下の通りで、

- openjdk: The OpenJDK **runtime** environment.
- openjdk-devel: The OpenJDK **development** tools.

単に実行環境が必要なだけなら前者の runtime = JRE のみでOKなはずです。
(認識の通り、開発を行う場合には`openjdk-devel` も必要)

Comment: 以下、補足です。おっしゃるように動作させるだけなら、JRE相当のopenjdkでことたりますが。単に実行環境が必要なだけでも、たとえば、システムとして長期間稼働させる場合、障害発生時にはJDKのもっているjhat,jstatあたりを使いたくなるケースがあります。あとから困らないように構築時にJDKをいれておくこともあります。このあたりは「何をしたいのか」によります。